# Django: Join two tables in a single query

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

In my template I have a table which I want to populate with data from two different tables which use foreign-keys.

The solution I find while googling around is to use values(), example of my queryset below:

```
data = Table1.objects.all().filter(date=today).values('table2__price')
```

**My template**

```
    {% for item in data %}
        <tr class="original">
          <td>{{ item.fruit }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.table2__price }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

It do fetch price from table2, but it also make the data (item.fruit) from Table1 disappear. If I remove the values field, Table1 populates accordingly.

Anyone have any feedback of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `all()` you can just write `Table1.objects.filter(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make use of [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), then you retrieve a queryset of *dictionaries*, that only contains the values specified. This is *not* a good idea. Not only because as you found out, it wiill thus no longer use the values in the model, but you will "*erode*" the model layer as well: it is no longer a `Table1` object, but a dictionary. Which is a form of a [*primitive obsession* antipattern <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

You can make use of [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to add extra attributes for the elements that arise from this queryset:

```
from django.db.models import F

data = Table1.objects.filter(date=today).annotate(
    table2__price=F('table2__price')
)
```

If there is however a `ForeignKey` (or `OneToOneField`) from `Table1` to `Table2`, you can select the columns of `Table2` in the same query with [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
data = Table1.objects.filter(date=today).select_related('table2')
```

in the template, you can then use:

```
{{ item.fruit }}
{{ item.table2.price }}
{{ item.table2.other_attr }}
```

The `.select_related(…)` part is not strictly necessary, but without it, it will make an extra query *per* item, thus this will produce an *N+1 problem*.

Comment: This seem to work! Would this work if I want let's say data from multiple columns in table2? Or are there another way of doing that, in case there are some "best practices" :-)

Comment: @massideux: is there a `ForeignKey` from `Table1` to `Table2`?

Comment: Yes, and I tried and it all works smooth by just adding another column within the annotate(). Thanks a lot WillEm! :)